# Why does brew download an older bazel version

Tags: homebrew, bazel

I'm trying to see how to install Bazel via brew and am encountering an issue.
Note I uninstalled all bazel version before doing this to simulate a new user.
According to the docs on [bazel's site](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install.html) it should work out of the box but I need to install explicitly from `bazelbuild/tap/bazel`.
Any thoughts?

```
➜  Homebrew git:(stable) brew tap bazelbuild/tap && brew tap-pin bazelbuild/tap && brew install bazel   git:(stable)
==> Pinned bazelbuild/tap
To restore the stashed changes to /usr/local/Homebrew run:
  'cd /usr/local/Homebrew && git stash pop'
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/bazel-0.15.2.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/39/390fd161839611a293e225c2dc91a37cab8d8fa7dfd4290cc680beb29c05fa15?__
###                                                                        4.9%^C
➜  Homebrew git:(stable) brew tap bazelbuild/tap && brew tap-pin bazelbuild/tap && brew install bazelbuild/tap/bazel
==> Pinned bazelbuild/tap
To restore the stashed changes to /usr/local/Homebrew run:
  'cd /usr/local/Homebrew && git stash pop'
==> Installing bazel from bazelbuild/tap
==> Downloading https://releases.bazel.build/0.17.2/release/bazel-0.17.2-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Bazel is not supported by the core homebrew anymore. You can open and pin the [bazel tap](https://github.com/bazelbuild/homebrew-tap) instead:

```
brew tap bazelbuild/tap
brew tap-pin bazelbuild/tap
brew upgrade bazel
```

https://blog.bazel.build/2018/08/22/bazel-homebrew.html

Comment: I don’t think this is the correct answer. The correct answer is either to uninstall bazel first or use the canonical name. Just using the tap doesn’t work

Comment: Tap-pin prioritizes the tap above core, so I don't think you need to uninstall the core formula. But I didn't try to be honest.

Comment: Verified that my answer is correct: applying the instructions from the site almost work, but eventually complain with _To upgrade to 0.17.2, run `brew upgrade bazel`_. So it was quite easy to correct my answer using `brew upgrade` rather than `brew install` in the last step.